# Is there any in-game guide for crafting recipies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Before you answer with your favorite web link, note that I am asking *specifically* in-game.

A friend of mine recently started playing Minecraft for the first time, and found very basic things like getting wood, creating tools, and making shelter to be very difficult.  It occurs to me that an in-game guide to crafting recipes would be helpful, but updates lately have gone in so many directions, I don't know if such a thing even exists in the game.

Is there any guide or indicator in vanilla Minecraft that would help a user figure out crafting recipes without having to resort to an external reference?

I am also *not* looking for a mod that creates one - if you can recommend one that would be alright, but it would not answer my question.

Comment: There is in the console version, it also has a tutorial world.  PC players are consigned to the wiki to find this basic information.

Comment: @EldritchWarlord You should provide that as an answer.

Comment: Good point, I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console versions the crafting menu shows all the recipes and provides hints about their use.  It even shows the proper arrangement of materials for the PC version's crafting system so you can use it to learn.

There's also a tutorial world in the console editions which covers most of the gameplay basics (including things like potion brewing, entering the Nether, and making golems).  Really console edition is the place to be for new Minecrafters.

If you have to play the PC version you'll just be stuck looking up everything in the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki).

Comment: There are also mods like NotEnoughItems which contain lists of recipes

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no in-game guide to create anything. The part about Minecraft that originally made it so much fun was finding all of these things out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On PC version, in a plain vanilla game, no there is no in-game recipe reference.
You can use a mod like above, but I think those are only for Forge server games. If you used a CraftBukkit or Spigot server instead, the Essentials plugin has the "/recipe NAME" command that will pop up a crafting grid with the necessary items in their correct positions. There are probably lots of different mods and plugins that can do this. I suggest Essentials because it's the one I use on my server worlds.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is!

**Here is an in-game screenshot!!**
[image: example in-game]

There is a mod that does exactly that:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods

Comment: "I am also not looking for a mod that creates one - if you can recommend one that would be alright, but it would not answer my question."

Comment: Sorry, you will need a mod :(